# Xamarin Android Visualizer SetDataCaptureListener throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Based on [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081356/how-to-work-with-onwaveformdatacapture-result-of-visualizer-object) and [this example](http://android.okhelp.cz/java_android_code.php?s=setDataCaptureListener) I've implemented a `Visualizer` using Xamarin.

```
myVisualizer = new Visualizer(0);
myVisualizer.SetEnabled(false);
myVisualizer.SetCaptureSize(Visualizer.GetCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
myVisualizer.SetDataCaptureListener(new VisualizerCapturer(), Visualizer.MaxCaptureRate, true, false);
```

The code works until I call `myVisualizer.SetDataCaptureListener(...)` and the exception

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException:
>   Specified cast is not valid. at
>   Android.Media.Audiofx.Visualizer.SetDataCaptureListener
>   (Android.Media.Audiofx.Visualizer+IOnDataCaptureListener listener,
>   System.Int32 rate, System.Boolean waveform, System.Boolean fft)
>   [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/9578cdcd/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.Media.Audiofx.Visualizer.cs:811

gets thrown. My `IOnDataCaptureListener` implementation is without any code (I've made breakpoints inside the methods, no method gets called before the exception gets thrown)

```
public class VisualizerCapturer : Visualizer.IOnDataCaptureListener
{
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] fft, int samplingRate)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] waveform, int samplingRate)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have absolutely no idea whats my problem and I hope anybody can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `Visualizer.IOnDataCaptureListener` does not inherit from `Java.Lang.Object` thus it is a plain C# class and not an Android Callable Wrapper (`ACW`) based class and thus your `VisualizerCapturer` object is not valid to be passed between the C# and Java runtimes.

Inherit your `VisualizerCapturer` from **`Java.Lang.Object`** and implement the `Visualizer.IOnDataCaptureListener` methods and you will be fine:

```
public class VisualizerCapturer : Java.Lang.Object, Visualizer.IOnDataCaptureListener
{
 ~~~~
}
```

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Glad I could help, happy Xam'ie Coding